# Agregar un nuevo item a mi lista - reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Estoy practicando un poco de react, y quise hacer un CRUD, el problema que tengo es al momento de agregar un nuevo elemento.
Logro que los datos nuevos le llegue a la funcion que esta en el padre llamada createNewItem (alli tengo un console.log), pero no puedo ver es nuevo item reflejado en la lista y ademas se agrega al segundo click sobre el boton "guardar", no al primero.
en que estoy fallando?
Gracias por su ayuda.
dejo un sandbox con el codigo

https://codesandbox.io/embed/wizardly-archimedes-x8jzn

Comment: Tu devolución y actualización en el state están bien. sólo puse un link para regresar a / en el botón cancelar y se ven los datos de la página. También hay que agregar el routeo para que cuando termine de actualizar el estado con el nuevo registro en createNewItem, active el componente raíz.

Comment: Hola @GerardoMonroyGonzález gracias, esta en el mismo link que adjunte? Gracias

Comment: Si, pero a mi no me deja grabar, no se como funcione en ese sentido el sandbox.io Pero ya está corregido para que veas tus cambios     `      <Link
            to="/">
          <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.cancelForm}>
            Cancelar
          </Button>
          </Link>`  la función cancelForm no es necesaria para navegar aquí

Comment: Está excelente ver el sandbox, sin embargo me parece que va a perderse algo en SOsp si no se mantiene la visibilidad del código para todos los miembros aquí. Sugiero a los que mantienen SO contemplen este modo de apoyar, incluyendo sandbox en lugar de snippets :=D

Comment: @GerardoMonroyGonzález, ya pude ver el cambio! gracias! a que te referias con agregar el routeo? si le pongo al boton guardar un link a '/' no veo los cambios, solo los veo si voy hacia atras con la flecha del browser.

Comment: recuerda que el <Link/> va sobre el botón cancelar para regresar y ver los cambios. Lo otro me refiero que comunmente cuando terminas y das guardar te regresa a la lista de elementos y sale de la forma. Hay que hacer un push al history de navegación que ya puse pero no lo hice jalar en la función de createNewItem. Por otro lado, acostúmbrate a usar el bootstrap desde inicio para hacer vistas fabulosas, recuerda que es lo que va a ver tu cliente o sponsor.

Comment: También la carga de datos iniciales se ejecuta en el componentDidMount() y allí se actualiza el status. mientras debes poner una condicional sobre el miembro que tiene la lista (deliverys debe estar inicializado en [] p.e.) para que informe al usuario que está cargando y no falle la presentación o render. (la condicional en el componente Home)

Comment: ahhah ya entendi! muchas gracias por tu ayuda, me sirvio mucho!

Answer (score 0):

Agrega una envoltura Link a tu botón cancelar y cuando regreses tu vista de detalle Home estará con los agregados que hayas aceptado en /details. Lo demás está correcto, aunque por ser de navegación la función del click no es necesaria.

```
<Link to="/"> 
  <Button variant="primary" type="submit" onClick={this.cancelForm}> Cancelar 
  </Button> 
</Link>
```